# Trouble sorting arrays within an array: Something in here is creating an undefined array element

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

So i've been making a website for a store inside my school to get some experience and maybe later on a career as a web dev. Programming the back end of the website was a lot more fun than I expected, until I encountered this issue that i've been debugging for literal hours and have made very little progress on.

I have recreated the situation in a slightly simpler function. Allow me to explain the purposes of everything:

`arrayMain`: The array that I am intending to sort. It contains more arrays that I wish to sort by the number in the 1 position.

`arrayBase`: Copy of `arrayMain` that is intended to never be edited. Mainly used to "unsort" `arrayMain` if desired.

`arrayTemp`: A copy of `arrayBase` that is used in a selection-sort. Repeatedly the item with the lowest number is moved back to `arrayMain`.

`min` and `transfer`: To move over 1 array element, the entirety of `arrayTemp` is scanned. `min` starts off as the number in the last item in the list. If a new minimum is detected, it is set to `transfer`. When all items are checked, `arrayTemp[transfer]` is moved into `arrayMain`.

```js
var arrayMain = [["a", 15, "c"], ["a", 18, "c"], ["a", 11, "c"] ,["a", 15, "c"], ["a", 25, "c"]]
var arrayBase = arrayMain.slice(0)

testFunc = function() {

  // Clear the main array and prepare to rebuild it in order
  arrayMain = []
  let arrayTemp = arrayBase.slice(0)

  // Length of the array times, find the element with smallest number in position 1 and move it over to arrayMain.
  // This is supposed to ignore the last element since that one does not require calculations
  for (let i = arrayTemp.length; i > 0; i--) {
    let min = arrayTemp[arrayTemp.length - 1][1], transfer = arrayTemp.length - 1
    for (let x = (arrayTemp.length - 2); x >= 0; x--) {
      if (arrayTemp[x][1] >= min) {
        min = arrayTemp[x][1]
        transfer = x
      }
    }
    arrayMain.unshift(arrayTemp[transfer])
    arrayTemp.splice(transfer, 1)
  }

  // Move over the last array element and log the results
  arrayMain.unshift(arrayTemp[0])
  console.log(arrayMain)
}

testFunc()
```

Expected result:

```
[ ["a", 11, "c"], ["a", 15, "c"], ["a", 15, "c"], ["a", 18, "c"], ["a", 25, "c"] ]
```

Actual result:

```
[ undefined, ["a", 11, "c"], ["a", 15, "c"], ["a", 15, "c"], ["a", 18, "c"], ["a", 25, "c"] ]
```

I know it's very easy to just remove `arrayMain[0]`, but I want to know if there's a way I can prevent this undefined element from appearing in the first place, or at least know what makes it.

Or, if you have your own way of sorting this that not only works but also does it faster, I guess i'll also accept that, but I really want to know where the `undefined` is coming from, because if I never figure that out I might end up in this situation again in the future.

Big thanks in advance.

Comment: `// Move over the last array element` - Add a `console.log(arrayTemp)` before the following/last `.unshift()` and you will see that there's no _"last array element"_ left in `arrayTemp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (let i = arrayTemp.length; i > 0; i--) {
```

As you insert your last element after the loop, your loop one time too much.

```
for (let i = arrayTemp.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
```

One more logical and readable way may be :

```
while (arrayTemp.length > 1)
{
    // your logic here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You loop all items in the outer loop and there you unshift the last item as well.

```js
const
    testFunc = function() {
        // Clear the main array and prepare to rebuild it in order
        arrayMain = [];
        let arrayTemp = arrayBase.slice(0)

        // Length of the array times, find the element with smallest number
        // in position 1 and move it over to arrayMain.
        // This is supposed to ignore the last element since that one does not
        // require calculations
        for (let i = arrayTemp.length; i > 0; i--) {
            let min = arrayTemp[arrayTemp.length - 1][1],
                transfer = arrayTemp.length - 1;
                
            for (let x = arrayTemp.length - 2; x >= 0; x--) {
                if (arrayTemp[x][1] >= min) {
                    min = arrayTemp[x][1];
                    transfer = x;
                }
            }
            arrayMain.unshift(arrayTemp[transfer])
            arrayTemp.splice(transfer, 1)
        }

        // Move over the last array element and log the results
 //           arrayMain.unshift(arrayTemp[0])
        console.log(arrayMain);
    };


var arrayMain = [["a", 15, "c"], ["a", 18, "c"], ["a", 11, "c"], ["a", 15, "c"], ["a", 25, "c"]]
var arrayBase = arrayMain.slice(0)

testFunc();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

To overcome this problem, you need to adjust the start value with `length - 1` and take `i` as index instead of using the `length`.

```js
const
    testFunc = function() {
        let arrayMain = [];
        let arrayTemp = arrayBase.slice(0),
            i = arrayTemp.length;

        while (--i) {
            let min = arrayTemp[i][1],
                transfer = arrayTemp.length - 1,
                x = i;
                
            while (x--) {
                if (arrayTemp[x][1] >= min) {
                    min = arrayTemp[x][1];
                    transfer = x;
                }
            }
            arrayMain.unshift(arrayTemp[transfer])
            arrayTemp.splice(transfer, 1)
        }

        arrayMain.unshift(arrayTemp[0])
        console.log(arrayMain);
    };


var arrayMain = [["a", 15, "c"], ["a", 18, "c"], ["a", 11, "c"], ["a", 15, "c"], ["a", 25, "c"]]
var arrayBase = arrayMain.slice(0)

testFunc();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```